# add text on plt.imshow

Tags: matplotlib, imshow

I have two ndarrays: Mat, labels
Currently I display Mat:

```
plt.imshow(Mat, cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=1, interpolation='None')
```

labels has the same shape as Mat, and lables[(i,j)] contains a label of Mat[(i,j)].
How can I show the label on each pixel?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest approach uses Seaborn's [heatmap](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html). When `annot=True` it prints the data values into the cells.  But `annot=` can also be a matrix of labels. In that case it is important to set the print format to string (`fmt='s'`). `annot_kws=` can set additional keywords, such as fontsize or color. `x` and `yticklabels` can be incorporated in the call to `heatmap()`, or be set afterwards using matplotlib.

An important benefit of the default coloring is that Sorn uses black on the light colored cells and white on the dark cells.

Here is an example that uses some utf8 characters as labels.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

M, N = 5, 10
mat = np.random.rand(M, N)
labels = np.random.choice(['X', '☀', '★', '♛'], size=(M, N))
ax = sns.heatmap(mat, cmap="inferno", annot=labels, annot_kws={'fontsize': 16}, fmt='s')
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

PS: There is a [matplotlib example](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_annotated_heatmap.html) in the documentation to create something similar without Seaborn. It can be easily adapted to print strings from a different matrix, and also a test can be added to change the color depending on the cell darkness.

Comment: the [maplotlib example](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_annotated_heatmap.html) was exactly what I was looking for